# How to use Reachability class to detect network status?

Tags: objective-c, network-programming, iphone-sdk-3.0, reachability

I am creating an app which requires internet. I want to use reachability class in my project and I want to detect if user has no internet connection whatever the technique is either wifi, Cellular. I want a step by step guide for this.

Comment: Did any answer help you? Just click the check mark to mark it as an accepted solution or vote it up. And please check your other questions for possible solutions, too. Thanks! :)   (And yes, this is copy-pasted so new users are aware of the voting system.)

Comment: This question has already been answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083701/how-to-check-for-an-active-internet-connection-on-iphone-sdk

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can start with [Reachability](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/Reachability/index.html) sample application. There is also some [entries on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=reachability+iphone) that are about the subject.