# How can i know when i have connection with my server using Reachability?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, reachability

i need to Implement in my app Error report. i have already have this error report but the problem is that i use the grabURLInBackground to send the error and it's not a good Idea because i need to save those error's in array and ONLY when i have connection with the server i need to send all of those error's together. so my Question is how do i "listen" to a server connection? 
how can i know when to send my error's ( Connection is Available ) ? do i need to do it in background? with what?
i hope you guy's Understood me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get a lot of example code code with Reachability. In fact you can google it.
I didn't found a solution which completely works for me as desired.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033042/how-to-use-reachability-class-to-detect-network-status) is a similar question, maybe.

And here is my test cases:

Connect your device to a WI-FI router, and unplug the WLAN from router, so has connection to WI-FI , but no connection to internet.

Case2:
Insert a SIM card, turn on the Allow data at setting via 3G, but the card has no 3G dataplan.

All of Reachability will say there is internet connection and all api calls are fake...